# A 7-step algorithm for finding the candy boxes

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Problem: there are $15$ boxes, of which $2$ contain candy and $13$ contain  grass. There's also a candy-detector machine that can be used to tell whether a particular set of boxes contains candy boxes in it: e.g. you could take $10$ boxes of your choice and it would say 'yes' if there's a candy box among them and 'no' if there isn't one.

The machine can only be used 7 times. Find an algorithm to locate the candy boxes with 100% certainty.

I tried brute-forcing it, but it seems to be complicated. Is there a smart way of solving this?

Comment: Just as a sanity check: information-theoretically it's doable. Because $\binom{15}{2} = 105 < 128 = 2^7$.

Comment: wait... what happened to the two answers people posted?

Comment: Both deleted by their authors.

Comment: @BenjaminWang query answered.

Comment: @Ingix query answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminary results.

---

Result-1

Immediate that if you **know** that there is exactly 1 candy box from a set of exactly $2^n$ boxes, then you will need exactly $n$ tests to guarantee determining which of the $2^n$ boxes has the candy.

---

Result-2

Suppose that you **know** that there are exactly 2 candy boxes from a set of exactly 7 boxes.  Can the 2 boxes be determined in no more than 5 tests?

Label the boxes $1,2,3,4,5,6,7.$

$T_1~$ (i.e. test 1) :  $~\{1,2\}.$ 
If this test fails, then you have 4 tests to determine which of the 2 boxes from $\{3,4,5,6,7\}$ have the candy.  Simply test boxes $3,4,5,6$ one at a time.

Therefore, WLOG, $T_1 : \{1,2\}$ succeeded. 
Now: $T_2 : \{3,4,5,6\}.$ 
If $T_2$ fails, then you have 3 tests left to check boxes $\{1,2,7\}.$  Simply check boxes $1,2$, one at a time.

Therefore, WLOG 
$T_1 : \{1,2\}$ succeeded and 
$T_2 : \{3,4,5,6\}$ also succeeded. 
By Result-1, the situation can be resolved with the 3 remaining tests.

---

Result-3

Suppose that you **know** that there are exactly 2 candy boxes from a set of exactly 10 boxes.  Can the 2 boxes be determined in no more than 6 tests?

Label the boxes $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.$

$T_1~$ :  $~\{1,2,3,4\}.$ 
If this test fails, then you have 5 tests to determine which of the 2 boxes from $\{5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ have the candy.  By Result-2, that is sufficient.

Therefore, WLOG, $T_1 : \{1,2,3,4\}$ succeeded. 
Now: $T_2 : \{5,6,7,8\}.$ 
If $T_2$ succeeds, then Result-1 can be applied against 
$\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\{5,6,7,8\}$ so the 4 remaining tests are sufficient.

Therefore, WLOG 
$T_1 : \{1,2,3,4\}$ succeeded and 
$T_2 : \{5,6,7,8\}$ failed. 
Now: $T_3 : \{9,10\}.$ 
If $T_3$ succeeds, then Result-1 can be applied against 
$\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\{9,10\}$ so the 3 remaining tests are sufficient.

If $T_3$ fails, then both boxes of candy are in $\{1,2,3,4\}$ so use the 3 remaining tests by testing $1,2,3$ one at a time.

---

Result-4

Suppose that you have 6 tests to use against 
$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}.$  Further suppose that you have
used the first test as follows:

$T_1: \{1,2,3,4\}.$  Further suppose that this test succeeded.

Can the situation be completely resolved by the 5 remaining tests - here it is unknown whether $\{1,2,3,4\}$ contains 1 candy box or 2 candy boxes.

$T_2: \{5,6,7,8\}.$ 
This test can be assumed to have failed, since otherwise, Result-1 can be applied (re 4 remaining tests) against 
$\{1,2,3,4\}, \{5,6,7,8\}.$

$T_3: \{9,10\}.$ 
Similar to the above, this test can also be assumed to have failed because otherwise, by Result-1, the 3 remaining tests can be applied against

$\{1,2,3,4\}, \{9,10\}.$

Consequently, with 3 tests remaining, it can be assumed that both candy boxes are in $\{1,2,3,4\}.$  Therefore, simply test $1,2,3$, one at a time.

---

---

Label the boxes $1,2,3, \cdots, 14,15.$

$T_1 : \{1,2,3,4,5\}.$ 
By Result-3, WLOG, $T_1$ succeeds, since otherwise, 6 tests are sufficient against $\{6,7,8, \cdots, 15\}.$

$T_2 : \{5,6,7,8,9\}.$ 
If $T_2$ fails, then the scenario precisely fits Result-4, with $\{1,2,3,4\}$ having been successfully tested, and $\{10,11,12,13,14,15\}$ still untested.  Note how the hypothetical failure of $T_2$ eliminates $\{5\}$ and allows the supposition that $\{1,2,3,4\}$ has been tested successfully.

Therefore, by Result-4, WLOG, $T_2$ succeeds.

$T_3 : \{5\}.$ 
If $T_3$ fails, with $T_1$ and $T_2$ both assumed to have succeeded, then there must be 1 candy box in $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and 1 candy box in $\{6,7,8,9\}.$  Then, by Result-1, the 4 remaining tests are sufficient against $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\{6,7,8,9\}.$

Therefore, it may be assumed that $T_3$ succeeds.

$T_4 : \{10,11,12,13,14,15\}.$ 
Regardless of whether $T_4$ succeeds or not, Result-1 kicks in.

If $T_4$ succeeds, then 3 tests are sufficient against $\{10,11,12,13,14,15\}.$

If $T_4$ fails, then 3 tests are sufficient against $\{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9\}.$

Comment: Thanks for answering! I didn't quite get the 'if T2 fails, then the scenario precisely fits Result-4' part. Don't we start with 6 tests to use in Result-4? And here we've already used T1 and T2.

Comment: @octagon_q Result-4 premises 6 tests, the first of which is $~T_1:\{1,2,3,4\}:~\text{success},~$ which implies **5 tests remaining**.  The actual *hypothetical* application is 7 tests: the first of which is $T_1:\{1,2,3,4,5\}:~\text{success},~$ and $~T_2:\{5,6,7,8,9\}:~\text{failure}.$  In this hypothetical, [1] $\{5\}$ is eliminated, which allows $T_1$ to be **re-characterized** as $~\{1,2,3,4\}: ~\text{success},~$ and [2] there are **5 tests remaining**.  Thus, the actual hypothetical results in a scenario that satisfies the premises of Result-4.